# Telegram bot privacy mode and groups

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Is it possible to programmatically enable/disable privacy mode and groups mode for the bot?

Can bot do it by itself??

Or only BotFather can do that?

Also, is the 20 bots restriction per account still a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change privacy mode using bot API, but you can use MTPROTO API to communicate with BotFather through a real Telegram account that is the owner of the bot. So the bot can't do that itself.

Yes, currently you can only create 20 bots per account.